# How to use CASE in WHERE clause for short circuiting CONTAINS

Tags: sql-server

I have a Stored Procedure for searching that takes several optional parameters.  One of those is @keywords defined as

```
@keywords nvarchar(1000) = null,
```

If @keywords is null or empty string, I want to short circuit, otherwise I need to search a full text index.  My logic used to look like this:

```
WHERE
(@keywords IS NULL OR CONTAINS( (Title, CrossRef, company_name), @keywords))
AND
-- other search terms
```

However, I just discovered that OR is not guaranteed to short circuit, so sometimes this returns an error for "empty full-text predicate."  Apparently CASE is supposed to be guaranteed to short circuit, but some versions of SQL server have a bug where this isn't the case.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
WHERE 
(1 = CASE
    WHEN @keywords IS NULL THEN 1
    WHEN @keywords = '""' THEN 1
    ELSE (CASE WHEN CONTAINS( (Title, CrossRef, company_name), @keywords) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
)
AND
-- other search terms
```

This still gives the "empty full-text predicate" error.  I'd be happy to just replace @keywords with something that will always match, but I'm not sure how to do that either.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using a SP, why not just throw this into [IF THEN ELSE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) blocks to implement your short-circuit logic.  Not only will it be easier to read, but the optimizer will like it better as well.

Comment: As I understand it I can't just put that part of the WHERE clause in an IF statement.  I'd have to put the whole query in, which would mean duplicating the rest of the query.  That may be the best solution here though.

Comment: You need to put one iteration of the query in the IF block and the other in the ELSE.  Basically you will have to write the query two different ways, and the IF will evaluate @keywords is NULL or empty.  If it is, use your short cut logic.  If it's not, don't.  In either case you'll end up with a tailored SQL Statement for the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing.  At the top of the SP:

```
DECLARE @fix_keywords nvarchar(1000)
SET @fix_keywords = @keywords
IF @keywords IS NULL OR @keywords = '' SET @fix_keywords = 'zqxvMatchNothing321'
```

and then

```
WHERE 
(@keywords IS NULL OR @keywords = '' OR CONTAINS( (Title, CrossRef, company_name), @fix_keywords))
AND
-- other search terms
```

I realize this is a bit hacky, but I think it's the best solution in my case, since I don't have to duplicate the entire query in an IF/ELSE.

Another possible solution would be to use dynamic SQL.